# Group by Agent name from Activity data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an activity table having case no,Agent and Team.The activity have number of rows for a single case.
Now my requirement is I need to show the Case numbers where the case transferred from one agent to another agent in a same team.

In the example 1 the case is transferred from Level 1 to Level 2 , and then it came back to level 1 agent.So I need this ticket.

Example 1:

```
Case no | Agent  | Team
--------|--------|-------
123     | Ramu   | Level1
123     | Ramu   | Level1
123     | Raja   | Level2
123     | Ravi   | Level1
```

Basically I need  case numbers for level 1 only , if its transferred more than 1 time

In the example 2 the case is transferred from Level 1 to Level 2 , and then it came back to level 2 agent. I don't need this ticket.

Example 2:

```
Case no | Agent  | Team
--------|--------|-------
1115    | Arya   | Level2
1115    | Arya   | Level2
1115    | Sekhar | Level2
1115    | Ravi   | Level1
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

> I need to show the Case numbers where the case transferred from one agent to another agent in a same team.

You can use `exists` to get the original rows:

```
select a.*
from activities a
where exists (select 1
              from activities a2
              where a2.caseno = a.caseno and
                    a2.team = a.team and
                    a2.agent <> a.agent
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired output you need some identity column in the table. Here i have added so the table should be like:

```
Id  Caseno  Agent   Team
1   123     Ramu    Level1
2   123     Ramu    Level1
3   123     Raja    Level2
4   123     Ravi    Level1
5   1115    Arya    Level2
6   1115    Arya    Level2
7   1115    Sekhar  Level2
8   1115    Ravi    Level1
```

and to fetch the data you can use this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Caseno
FROM    activity
WHERE   Caseno NOT IN (
        SELECT  Caseno
        FROM    ( SELECT    LAG(Team) OVER ( ORDER BY Id ) AS Prev,
                            Caseno, Team
                  FROM      activity ) T
        WHERE   T.Prev = Team
                AND T.Team <> 'Level1' );
```

To check the demo you can use the link:
**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8590a33e28680f588164ef125c85504d)**